# Proof of nonexistence of two nonzero elements $x,y$ of some field such that $xy=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that there cannot exist two $x,y$ elements of some field such that $xy=0$.

I started by dividing by $x$ and getting that if $x$ is nonzero, then $y$ must be equal to zero, which tells nothing about this problem. How could I tackle this?

Comment: two non-zero elements you mean?  as stated, the claim is false.

Comment: @lulu OP probably forgot that condition.

Comment: with the non-zero condition restored, the problem is trivial and your proof is complete.  since $x\neq 0$ we can divide both sides by $x$, yielding $y=0$ contrary to assumption.

Comment: You've proved it, since you proved that if one of the factors is nonzero, the other is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $x,y \neq 0$ such that $x \cdot y = 0$. Since they are nonzero, they have multiplicative inverses - i.e. $\exists x^{-1} \text{ such that } x^{-1} \cdot x = 1$

Then $y = 1 \cdot y = (x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot y = x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot y) = x^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0$, assuming that you've already proven that $a \cdot 0 = 0$ from the field axioms (if you haven't, it's also a relatively simple proof).

However, we assumed that $y \neq 0$ and proved that $y = 0$, which is a contradiction, thus our assumption is impossible, hence there are no $x,y \neq 0$ such that $x \cdot y = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Invertible elements of a ring $R$ cannot be zero divisors. To show this, let $r\in R$ be invertible. Suppose there is an element $s\in R$ with $rs=0$. Then $s = 1s= (r^{-1}r)s = r^{-1}(rs) = r^{-1}0 = 0$. The last step says that the zero element $0$ in $R$ is absorbing, i.e., for each $r\in R$, $r0 = r(r+(-r)) = r^2-r^2=0$.

In a field, all elements up to the zero element are invertible. So there are no zero divisors there ($0$ is not considered as a zero divisor).